# How can I add external value to DataSource by Sql command?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I read my dropdownlost data from one of my tables on database . I want to add an external value ( Select ) to my dropdownlist .. 
This is my datasorource sql code

```
SELECT        ID, Part, fxCarId
FROM            tblParts
WHERE        (fxCarId = @fxCarId)
UNION
SELECT        TOP (1) 0 AS Expr2, 'Select' AS Expr1
FROM            tblParts AS tblParts_1
```

How can I add this ' Select ' text into my dropdownlist ?

Comment: What do you mean by external value? a variable? or your custom listitem?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz : I connect my dropdownlist to a Datasource .. But in my table there is no a row with Please Select text .. I want to add it into my Dropdownlist .. I mean a text .. an external text that there is not in my table .

Comment: This is not an elegant solution using union...there is a property called AppendDataBound in dropdown list, use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were along the right lines, but your union requires that both statements have the same number of columns, you had 2 columns in the top part and only 2 on the bottom.

SQL-Server also doesn't require that you select directly from a table, so rather than doing `SELECT TOP 1` from a table, you can specify your values directly:

```
SELECT  ID, Part, fxCarId
FROM    tblParts
WHERE   fxCarId = @fxCarId
UNION
SELECT  0, 'Select', 0
```

What I tend to do to ensure "Select" is at the top of any drop down is add a SortOrder column, this way you can ensure "Select" is the default value at the top of the list, but the remainder of the drop down is in alphabetical order which is more logical for the user.

```
SELECT  ID, Part, fxCarId, 1 [SortOrder]
FROM    tblParts
WHERE   fxCarId = @fxCarId
UNION
SELECT  0, 'Select', 0, 0
ORDER BY SortOrder, Name
```

Answer (score 2):

To add a default list item do the following:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Please select.." Value="SomeValue" Selected="true"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: You would need to set [AppendDataBoundItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) to true as well otherwise your ListItem would be overridden during databinding.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand then do it like this.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" DataTextField="Part" DataValueField="Id"
                                    AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Text--" Value="-1" />
                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

**AppendDataBoundItems="true"** is most important. and make your SQL query.

```
SELECT        ID, Part, fxCarId
FROM            tblParts
WHERE        (fxCarId = @fxCarId)
```

No union. hope it helps